# Restrict direct access of internal pages in SAPUI5 application

Tags: sapui5

In my UI5 application I have to ensure that if a user closes a tab, then opens a new tab and pastes a direct link to an internal page there, the application routes him to the login page.

Here is the example:

1. A user gets to the following view and copies the direct link, e.g., `https://myapp/#/productsList`
2. User closes the tab
3. User opens a new tab and pastes the link there.
   I want to make sure that application will route him to the login page: `https://myapp.com`

I implemented the following routing logic:

```json
"routes": [{
    "pattern": "",
    "name": "login",
    "target": "login"
},…]
…
"targets": {
    "login": {
        "viewID": "login",
        "viewName": "Login"
    },…
}
```

How can I achieve such behavior with native UI5 tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this cannot be achieved by configuration of the routes in the *Manifest.json*. Usually, logins and authorization of users should be handled by the server itself: for example Apache, Tomcat, or Nginx, or by any other OpenID or OAuth solution. For instance, the Nginx [documentation](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/configuring-http-basic-authentication/).

Back to your problem, a simple solution for checking if a user already passed/has seen the login page. I would implement it in the following way.

In the *Components.js* register a model `loginModel`:

```js
let oLoginModel = new JSONModel({
    bUserLoggedIn = false;
});

this.setModel(oLoginModel, "loginModel");
```

If a user has seen/passed your login page, set the property to `true`.

Define your other routes in the *Manifest.json*. In the controllers of your views, attach a listener in the `onInit` and check if user has seen login page, if not navigate to login directly:

```js
onInit: function() {
    this.getRouter().getRoute("sampleRoute")
        .attachPatternMatched(this._onRouteMatched, this);
},

_onRouteMatched: function(oEvent) {
    if (!this.getModel("loginModel").getProperty("/bUserLoggedIn")) {
        let oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
        oRouter.navTo("login");
    }
},
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I have one concern regarding this approach: what happens if a user changes the value of `bUserLoggedIn` via DevTools? Is this technique security-reliable?

Comment: Hi, 
no it's definetely not security-reliable. A security-reliable solution checks for security token, cookie, session cookie, which is issued by a server like mentioned in my post. It's just a way to have some kind Anonymous or logged in area in your sapui5 application.
The best solution would be to have authentication on server side and after succesfull login you have your UI5 application content with no difference in logged in or logged out.
Then all is secured and no one can manipulate in devTools.

Comment: Thanks! I agree, all security-related functionality must be implemented in a proper way and rely on server-side as the only trusted node.